# Jazz Harmonic Analysis of "The Way You Look Tonight"

Tags: theory, chords, learning, jazz, analysis

[image]

So I was asked to do an analysis of The Way You Look Tonight, but we didn't need to include the roman numerals. Just the symbols. Apparently it still isn't right, so is there anything I'm missing? In the B section I'm sure it changes to the key of Ab major then in the last 2 measures it goes back to F major.

Comment: Please clarify what is your question. Is it a homework for a course you're taking? Doesn't the teacher explain what kind of analysis they request?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you’re required to do to bracket the 2-5’s and use an arrow to show the resolution of dominant chords. If there is something else required post it in the question or in comments.

I see 3 things missing, an arrow in the 1st ending going back to A and also in bars 2 and 9 of the bridge the Ao/F7 should have an arrow to the Bbm7. You are right in that the song modulates up a m3 to Ab in the bridge then back to F for the last A.